# Como faço para trocar a posição de dois nomes na tabela utilizando botões para cima e para baixo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, array, front-end

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Exemplo de Paginação</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    let lsAlunos = ["Alef Mourão dos Santos", "Andre Alex", "Danilo Rodrigues Soares", "Dhiego de Sampaio", "Emerson de Ferto", "Gabriel de Oliveira ", "Jhoune Souza Justino", "Josef Gildevan Santos", "João Santos Chagas", "Julio Lima", "Jônatas Maciel", "Loren Muniz Ferreira", "Luna Cavalcante", "Marcos Silva", "Marcos Barbosa da Silva", "Tais Pereira Melo", "Yudi Medeiros Santos", "Marco Pereira Silva"];


    pgAtual = 0;

    function carregarTabela(pg) {
      tamanhoArray = Math.ceil((lsAlunos.length) / 5);
      if (pg <= 0 || pg > tamanhoArray) {
        return;
      }

      pgAtual = pg;
      fim = (pg * 5);
      inicio = fim - 5;
      txLinhas = "";
      for (i = inicio; i < fim; i++) {
        if (lsAlunos[i] == undefined) break;
        txLinhas += `<tr><td>${Number(i) + 1}</td><td>${lsAlunos[i]}</td></tr>`;
      }
      document.getElementById("corpoTabela").innerHTML = txLinhas;
      itemLista = document.getElementById("pg-" + pg);
      itemLista.classList.add("active");

      antigo = document.getElementById("pgAT");
      if (antigo.value != '') {
        itemLista = document.getElementById("pg-" + antigo.value);
        itemLista.classList.remove("active");
      }
      antigo.value = pg;
    }

    function mudarPagina(pg) {
      carregarTabela(pgAtual + pg);
    }
  </script>

  <input type="hidden" value="" id="pgAT">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Linha
        </th>
        <th>
          Nome dos Alunos
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="corpoTabela">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center" id="paginacao">



  </ul>
  <script>
    lsPagina = `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="carregarTabela(document.getElementById('pgAT').value -1)">Anterior</a></li>`
    tamanhoArray = Math.ceil((lsAlunos.length) / 5);
    for (i = 0; i < tamanhoArray; i++) {
      lsPagina += `<li id='pg-${Number(i)+1}' class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="carregarTabela(${Number(i)+1})">${Number(i)+1}</a></li>`
    }
    lsPagina += `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="carregarTabela(Number(document.getElementById('pgAT').value) +1)">Próximo</a></li>`;
    document.getElementById("paginacao").innerHTML = lsPagina;
    carregarTabela(1);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente precisa achar a referência da TR, pois quer mover a linha toda, em seguida encontrar a referência da linha anterior ou da próxima e move a TR.

Se tiver um botão, ele estará em algum lugar dentro da TR, portanto, se tiver a referência do botão, pode usar o [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) para obter a referência do elemento "pai". No exemplo abaixo, adicionei os botões em uma nova TD, então precisa usar `.parentNode` duas vezes, pois uma vez irá retornar TD, que é o "pai" onde está o botão, e a segunda a TR, que é o "pai" do TD. Também adicionei abaixo uma *function* que recebe por parâmetro o botão com `this` e a ordem, que usei -1 para anterior e 1 para o próximo.

A partir daí, precisa decidir se quer mover para cima ou para baixo. Para cima seria o elemnto anterior, que podemos obter usando [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling), que vai retornar o nó anterio no "mesmo nível" do DOM, ou seja a TR anterior, e para o elemento a seguir podemos usar [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

Por fim, para mover o elemento devemos inserir a TR em questão antes ou depois do elemento "irmão" (*sibling*), para isso podemos usar [`before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before) ou [`after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after), respectivamente. Abaixo um código demonstrando:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <script>
    let lsAlunos = ["Alef Mourão dos Santos", "Andre Alex", "Danilo Rodrigues Soares", "Dhiego de Sampaio", "Emerson de Ferto", "Gabriel de Oliveira ", "Jhoune Souza Justino", "Josef Gildevan Santos", "João Santos Chagas", "Julio Lima", "Jônatas Maciel", "Loren Muniz Ferreira", "Luna Cavalcante", "Marcos Silva", "Marcos Barbosa da Silva", "Tais Pereira Melo", "Yudi Medeiros Santos", "Marco Pereira Silva"];


    pgAtual = 0;

    function carregarTabela(pg) {
      tamanhoArray = Math.ceil((lsAlunos.length) / 5);
      if (pg <= 0 || pg > tamanhoArray) {
        return;
      }

      pgAtual = pg;
      fim = (pg * 5);
      inicio = fim - 5;
      txLinhas = "";
      // aqui cria um par de botões, pode usar qualquer elemento que quiser e aplicar estilo
      var ordenador = "<td><button onclick='ordenar(this,-1)'>Cima</button><button onclick='ordenar(this,1)'>Baixo</button></td>"
      
      for (i = inicio; i < fim; i++) {
        if (lsAlunos[i] == undefined) break;
        txLinhas += `<tr><td>${Number(i) + 1}</td><td>${lsAlunos[i]}</td>` + ordenador + `</tr>`;
      }
      document.getElementById("corpoTabela").innerHTML = txLinhas;
      itemLista = document.getElementById("pg-" + pg);
      itemLista.classList.add("active");

      antigo = document.getElementById("pgAT");
      if (antigo.value != '') {
        itemLista = document.getElementById("pg-" + antigo.value);
        itemLista.classList.remove("active");
      }
      antigo.value = pg;
    }

    function mudarPagina(pg) {
      carregarTabela(pgAtual + pg);
    }
    
    function ordenar(btn, ordem) {
       //            BUTTON  TD      TR
       //  trAtual ir apontar para a TR de onde foi clicado o botão
       var trAtual = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
       
       // se for 1 é para baixo, então valida o nextSibling e insere depois (after)         
       if (ordem == 1 && trAtual.nextSibling != null) {
          trAtual.nextSibling.after(trAtual);
       // se for -1 é para cima, então valida o previousSibling e insere antes (before)         
       } else if (ordem == -1 && trAtual.previousSibling != null) {
         trAtual.previousSibling.before(trAtual);
       }
    }
    
  </script>

  <input type="hidden" value="" id="pgAT">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Linha
        </th>
        <th>
          Nome dos Alunos
        </th>
        <th>Ordenar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="corpoTabela">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center" id="paginacao">



  </ul>
  <script>
    lsPagina = `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="carregarTabela(document.getElementById('pgAT').value -1)">Anterior</a></li>`
    tamanhoArray = Math.ceil((lsAlunos.length) / 5);
    for (i = 0; i < tamanhoArray; i++) {
      lsPagina += `<li id='pg-${Number(i)+1}' class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="carregarTabela(${Number(i)+1})">${Number(i)+1}</a></li>`
    }
    lsPagina += `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="carregarTabela(Number(document.getElementById('pgAT').value) +1)">Próximo</a></li>`;
    document.getElementById("paginacao").innerHTML = lsPagina;
    carregarTabela(1);
  </script>
</body>
```

Note que, ainda validei se o `previousSibling` e o `nextSibling` não são `null`, isso porque como é um elemento irmão que tem de estar no mesmo nível, a primera e a última TRs vão retornar null, porque não há mais elementos TR antes ou depois.